# How do I "Create a Reference To a Different Workbook" that supports closed workbooks

Tags: excel, file, reference, worksheet

I want to do something like this:
[Create a Reference To a Different Workbook](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html) (look for this section in the page).
However, the instruction says that the documents must be opened for the INDIRECT function to work.

How can I make it work even if the documents are closed?
Any other solutions / alternatives?
I don't want to open each file and link it manually.
I want to be able to input the filename only, assuming the files are all in the same folder.

Comment: I also tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890484/formula-referencing-other-workbooks  
Doesn't work if the documents are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a UDF version of INDIRECT (INDIRECT.EXT) available from http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english/ that allows access to external workbooks even when they are closed

**EDIT**

Just checked the page and the download link doesn't work, but the download files can be found [here](http://xcell05.free.fr/downloads/), including the download for MoreFunc version 5.06 which contains the INDIRECT.EXT function